# programmatically get all nodes from drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am trying to get all nodes of a certian type from drupal. 
I have tried many ways to achieve that, but maybe due to my lack of Drupal custom module programming experience I couldn't achieve my desire.
the closest way that I found on the web, is this:

```
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type','news')->execute();
    $nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

- the first line returns an object of id's
- the second line returns the nodes of those id's

this looks easy and straight forward. but, this is the output!

`{
  "59": {
    "in_preview": null
  },
  "61": {
    "in_preview": null
  }
}`

can someone please help, what is wrong? and is this the correct way to do it ?

I want to take the nodes then search every one of them ( I am making some sort of search engine) so I expect some kind of an object that I can then extract the heading, body ... etc, from. is this the correct way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually returns node objects

```
$nodes =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
```

perhaps your output gives minimal results and not objects.  If you inspect with a proper debugger you will see the objects.

Perhaps its better to actually get one node object at a time if you expect too many nodes to be returned from the query

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1) //published or not
  ->condition('type', 'news') //content type
  ->pager(10); //specify results to return
$nids = $query->execute();

foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid); 
  $body = $node->body->value;
  $title = $node->title->value;
  //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This did the trick.
but can i ask you, what do you mean by inspecting with a proper debugger. i need to know the structure of the node object, can you tell me?

Comment: I consider `xdebug` to be a PROPER debugger but it might be a headache to setup with your favorite code editor (vscode, atom, netbeans, phpstorm etc) ... Perhaps the easiest way to *inspect variables* in drupal is using `kint()` which is probably good enough for your purpose ... read more https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: `$title = $node->title->value;` this is great but how to retrieve the translation based on interface language

Comment: Entity query service will be deprecated see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2849874